# how to make a popup video always in the center of screen even after use fullscreen control button using jquery mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, html5-video

i want to make an app that will play some videos. i use phonegap desktop with jquery mobile and phonegap developer app . i want to play a video by a popup.  i use data position to window to make the popup position in the center of screen. the problems are:

1. when i run my file in phonegap developer app, sometimes the popup appears perfectly in the center, but sometimes, it appears rather to right side.
   it shows like this
   [image]

[image]

2. when i press the fullscreen button control on the video and then press again the button to minimize video, it makes popup video moves to the right corner of the screen. it shows like this

[image]

please help me how to make the popup video always in the center even when i use fullscreen mode or after use fullscreen mode.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
 <script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
 <script src="jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
 <title>Hello World</title> 
</head>
<body>
 <div data-role="header"></div>
 <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
  <a href="#popupBasic" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-icon-video  ui-btn-icon-top">play</a>
   <div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic" data-position-to="window" >
    <video width="block" height="auto"   id="video_mute" controls>
     <source src="bilangan/bilangan_1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video> 
   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed my problem. I used this code:

```css
style="position: fixed; left: 50%; top: 50%; transform:translate(-50%,-50%);-moz-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);-webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);"
```